# Blueimp Gallery pdf support

Tags: jquery, pdf, image-gallery, blueimp

I'm using blueimp gallery to show some uploaded images from customers

occasionally they upload also pdf files and currently we have to open manually, while would be great to be preview also pdf in blueimp gallery.

From documentation I see that can be "easily" add support to other content type(s):

https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#example-html-text-factory-implementation

with very little imagination... i tried:

```
css:

.blueimp-gallery > .slides > .slide > .pdf-content {
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 60px auto;
    padding: 0 60px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    text-align: left;
    color:white;
}

js:

blueimp.Gallery.prototype.applicationFactory = function (obj, callback) {
    var $element = $('<div>')
            .addClass('pdf-content')
            .attr('title', obj.title);
    $.get(obj.href)
        .done(function (result) {
            $element.html(result);
            callback({
                type: 'load',
                target: $element[0]
            });
        })
        .fail(function () {
            callback({
                type: 'error',
                target: $element[0]
            });
        });
    return $element[0];
};

    $('#blueimpGallery-button').on('click', function (event) {
        blueimp.Gallery([
            {
                title: 'Test pdf_1',
                href: '/docs/test1.pdf',
                type: 'application/pdf'
            },
            {
                title: 'Test pdf_2',
                href: '/docs/test2.pdf',
                type: 'application/x-pdf'
            },
            {
                title: 'Test pdf_3',
                href: '/docs/test3.pdf',
                type: 'application/x-pdf'
            }

        ]);
    })
```

and rather unexpectedly.. it runs, but pdf is not recognized and is shown the source code
like this:
[image: screenshot]
I can imagine that, at least, is a problem of mime type, but I have no idea how to fix it

can suggest direction?
Thanks

Comment: Try the file upload instead --- https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Sorry, I've not understood your advice: perhaps file upload has hidden features that can be exploited, but I need to show pdf's in the gallery

Comment: you have a gallery in file upload too + you can upload any files. I presume when you click on a pdf to view it it will use the browser to open it. Anyway i think you will need to seperate the 2. Gallery is for viewing images only unless there a plugin outhere to add to open PDF in the gallery

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue and here's a "workable" solution. I'm using ASP.Net MVC.

I detect the file extension and display a static pdf icon image and in the anchor tag I've added a custom onclick event to open the pdf file in a new window. *But make sure your pdf is rendered with appropriate headers (i.e. "application/pdf")*

```
<span>
@{
bool IsPDF = item.FileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf");
    string resURL = Url.Action("GetFile", "MyController") + "?" + item.CodeStr;
    string imgURL = !IsPDF ? resURL : Url.Content("~/Content/Images/pdf.png");
    string target = !IsPDF ? "" : " onClick=\"window.open('" + resURL + "', '_blank')\""; // SO : 13335954
 }

<a href="@resURL" @Html.Raw(target) title="@item.FileName @item.FileTypeTitle">
    <img src="@imgURL" width="150px" alt="@item.Comment" />
</a>
</span>
```

The code is specific to my app the above is in Razor syntax (hope not difficult to infer). *Let me know if anyone has got a better solution*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, and sorry for late reply.  
actually I've not found a solution yet, I'm currently focused on other issues.
I've been evaluating to convert pdf to jpg/png but I think it will not be easy (since working in old asp).
About appropriate header: I added `'application/pdf'` as title but not sure it is enough: and I presume issue is right there: clearly the file is correct pdf file: if I open in a frame or in a page is rendered correctly.
I would appreciate If have other suggestions.

Comment: Joe, you'd be surprised to know that Safari is able to render pdf file inline (i.e. like image). But others don't. I've opted for another option - I create an image of the uploaded pdf (as xyz.pdf.img) and then use that image in gallery! Now I'm stuck to find a free pdf to image tool in .Net. My post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706662/free-pdf-to-image-tool-for-commercial-asp-net-web-app

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/aspfpdf/tutorials

That's completely free, and is ASP.. but classic ASP
(actually... jscript) but it works well

Comment: Thx Joe. That looks old school. Also it seems to be creating pdf file - rendering pdf in browser seems far. I opted for my image based solution using Spire.PDF tool (free for 1st 3 pages). Using image instead of pdf resolves all the issues.

Comment: yes, old school.. but I wrongly read your post: I understood you were willing to create pdf not convert pdf to image.
I will try posting on blueimp gallery github.. hoping somebody will answer, if have some good news I will post you